# Transposing data where amount of rows differ

Tags: excel, vba

I need to move data in a row to columns. Basically a transpose.

From the table below I am trying to turn each email into only a single row rather than having the recipients down column B. The really tricky part (for me) is that the amount of rows per email will differ because of the amount of recipients varies. Is there a way to get the recipient data to move from multiple rows to a single row?

```
Email 1   Recipient 1   
          Recipient 2   
          Recipient 3   
Email 2   Recipient 1   
          Recipient 2   
Email 3   Recipient 1   
          Recipient 2
```

Comment: Are you saying you need a VBA Macro to complete it because you're doing this very frequently, or are you just assuming there isn't a way of easily doing this in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that doesn't require VBA, which is a simpler approach if you don't need to do this a lot.

If you want to get all emails into a single cell, you can do this just using a formula in the third column. Assuming your data starts in A1 with no headings, just paste this formula into C1 and fill down:

```
=if(A2<>"",B1,B1 & ";" & C2)
```

This formula kinds of works from the bottom up.

If the next row in column A has a value, then the next row is a new email, so the current row is the last row of the current email. In which case, start with the current recipient.

If the next row in column A doesn't have a value, then the next row is part of the same email, so the current recipient can be added to the list of recipients. (Adding it to the start of the list keeps the recipients in the same order.)

The result is that column C will have the full list of recipients in a single cell on the rows which have an email in column A.

The last email will have an extra semicolon at the end, which we could get rid of with a bit more complexity, but if you're just sending emails, it doesn't matter and this is easier to understand!

The values in column C in the "in-between" rows are just working values and aren't required. You can get rid of the in-between rows entirely:

Copy the entire table; paste as values (over itself or to a new sheet); filter the table setting the email column equal to blanks (to display the in-between rows), then select and delete all visible rows. Clear the filter to be left with just your emails and full recipients. You can then also delete column B, which contains just the first recipient for each email.

This is now suitable to use for emailing. However, if you actually need the recipients split out into separate columns, then just use the Text-to-Columns function:

Select the column with consolidated emails, go to the Data tab on the ribbon, click Text-to-Columns, choose Delimited and click Next, choose Semicolon as the delimiter and click Finish. Voila!

Comment: Hi Michael,  not sure how you thought of that and it's not the way I was thinking of doing it but you my friend are a genius.  It has worked perfectly.

Comment: Super awesome idea on how to move the emails to the line above will remember this for future use.

Comment: Note that this formula assumes that column A only has each email identified once, against the first recipient. If your data is in a database format, where say "Email 1" is repeated for every recipient for that email, the formula needs to change to instead search for changes in column A: =if(A2<>A1,B1,B1 & ";" & C2)